# aws ec2 instance Permission denied (publickey). Other Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello when creating the instance i have missed to attach a private key to the aws ec2 instance now unable to login via ssh as there is no private key attached

what i did was clone of instance and launched installed and added the key to that instance
[image]

added key to it yet dint work

refereed articles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfOsytNUq1w

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you used to login to the instance, and the error message you are receiving. You can use `ssh -vvv` to show more debug information. Also, which AMI did you use to launch the instance (Amazon Linux, Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting via the command line ensure that you're specifying the PEM key using the syntax below

```
ssh -i path/to/key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```

Also ensure that the `path/to/key.pem` has permissions of `400` with the owner as your user.

You can validate this by running `ls -lah path/to/key.pem` and change the permissions by running `chmod 400 path/to/key.pem`